# NET Standard library refer .NETCore

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version, .net-standard

I am new to the Microsoft `Core` world and wanted create a class library that targets the .NET standard. I was using the Visual Studio IDE 2017 and picked a class library project template listed under `.NET Standard`.

When I expand the SDK on the .NET standard project structure, I could see `Microsoft.NETCore.Platform 1.1.0` as reference.

[image: Reference]

As per my understanding, .NET Core, .NET Framework, Mono, Universal Windows Platform, etc. uses .NET Standard and not other-way around. Please correct me.

**Question:**

1. What is the relevance of Microsoft.NETCore.Platform 1.1.0 reference under SDK?

Comment: Your understanding is mostly correct. They don't *use* .NET Standard as much as *implement* it. I'm not sure why the NETCore piece is there though, sorry

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, Thank you. I have been searching wide to get an answer. Please do post it if you happen to find one.

Comment: After reading the documentation he linked, I think Lex's answer is correct. Nothing in there indicates this dependency will cause your .NET Standard library any problems.

Comment: VS2017 shipped too soon to support any other targets than .NETCore 1.1.  .NETStandard version 2.0 needs to be done first.  The new standard to replace them all.  Scheduled for spring 2017, it is getting pretty sunny out there now but it isn't done yet.  We'll probably get it delivered in an update.  Count on hundreds of bugs before it gets reasonably stable, this is work in progress.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thanks. Honestly, I am not worried on the completeness of VS 2017 since maturity will only be achieved over various years out in market. My concern was whether or not my understanding is correct on how Microsoft's new initiatives relates or depended each other. It clearly confused me to see .NETCore dependency on .NETStandard project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly it is used for the following purposes,

> Provides runtime information required to resolve target framework, platform, and runtime specific implementations of .NETCore packages.
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/

and more can be found if you check the source code,

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/c2588415e91ca1d44885ac0bbe9bf8268adc4b48/pkg/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/readme.md

It is a cross platform package, not bind to any specific platform, but with a wrong name. As you asked, "NETCore" part is confusing and should be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I class library which I am creating is targeting a specific .NETStandard and not NETCore. The idea was exercise on how to create reusable dll, across .NET Framework ( CLR), .NETCore (CoreCLR) and UWP using .NETStandard.

Comment: “NETCore” in the package name does not prevent you from doing what you want. Ignore that please. Like I said, "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" is cross platform. Your class library would be indeed against .NET Standard, and can be reused everywhere.

Comment: Thank you. It is a sin to confuse folks who spend time to learn new radical changes across all of Microsoft's portfolio. I am still learning these and want things straight.