# Can UWP run in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, .net-core

When I create new UWP project it automatically references .NET Core. Is it possible to run it on .NET? Why it needs .NET Core? I can't find any valuable information about this...

Comment: I think that with .Net Standard 2.0 UWP will be improved.

Comment: The desktop version of .NET can use UWP classes, although this isn't exactly encouraged by the project templates and a complete UWP user interface is unrealistic.  But a UWP project always targets .NETCore.  They were hoping that it would make them competitive in the mobile computing business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs .NET Core because it is *built* on .NET Core, much like WPF is built on the .NET framework.

So no, you cannot change it to run on the standard .NET framework any more than you can make WPF run on .NET Core.

Comment: Why is it built on .NET Core when it only works with Microsoft technologies? Wouldn't be .NET sufficient?

Comment: @BradleyDotnet, Is it .NET Core , .NET Framework, Mono ,Universal Windows Platform built on top of .NETStandard ?  I have similar question here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544754/net-standard-library-refer-netcore

Comment: @MacakM  I'm guessing porting .NET framework to the ARM platform proved to be too troublesome and they already had a cross-platform solution at that point. Just my guess

Comment: @Nair All of those *implement* .NET standard (well, except for Mono). Its not quite the same thing :) I'll look at your question also

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Core Framework is a new version of .NET for modern device and cloud workloads. It’s a general-purpose and modular implementation of the Microsoft .NET Framework that can be ported and used in many different environments for a variety of workloads.

and No, you cannot run UWP project on .Net
althousg if you install previous version of VS then you can run it on .NET